# How to do CIFAR-10 with PyTorch on CUDA?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm following the CIFAR-10 PyTorch tutorial at [this pytorch page](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html) , and can't get PyTorch running on the GPU. The code is exactly as in the tutorial.

The error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(file path)/CIFAR10_tutorial.py", line 116, in <module>
   outputs = net(images)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "(file path)/CIFAR10_tutorial.py", line 65, in forward
x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)).cuda())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 491, in __call__
result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 301, in forward
self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
```

My CUDA version is 9.0, Pytorch 0.4.0. I have used tensorflow-gpu on the machine, so I know CUDA is set up correctly. Where exactly must I use .cuda() and .to(device) as suggested in the tutorial?

Comment: How are we supposed to tell you without seeing the code you actually wrote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm leaving an answer, in case anyone else is stuck on the same.

First, configure Pytorch to use the GPU if available

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
```

Then, in the **init** function, cast to gpu by calling .cuda() on *every* element of the NN, e.g.

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 24, 5).cuda()
self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2).cuda()
```

If you're not sure about the GPU, call **.to(device)** on every element.

In the **forward(self, x)** function, before the steps, I did

```
x = x.to(device)
```

Right after net object is created, cast it to device by

```
net.to(device)
```

All inputs and labels should be cast to device before any operation is performed on them.

```
inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
```

I am, skipping writing the entire code as the link has already been mentioned in the question. If there are seem to be a few redundant casts to gpu, they're not breaking anything. I might also put together an ipynb with the changes.